# need to join data from 4 tables using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to join data from 4 tables:

```
PROVIDERS - main source
TYPE
CATEGORY
SERVICE
LANGUAGE
```

I need to get language name instead of ID, same for other tables like this:

so I need to:

```
select *
from PROVIDERS,
     type,
     category,
     service,
     language
where providers.language = languages.ID
  and providers.category = category.ID
  and providers.service = service.id
  and providers.type = type.id
  and provider.id = 1
```

is this all or need to use inner join or something else?

Comment: Well, we stopped writing queries this way circa 1992, so I guess it's up to you if you wish to *join* us

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: *is this all or need to use inner join or something else?* If you're sure that each value from `providers` mentioned in a query is present in ref. tables then this is enough (after converting cartesian syntax to INNER JOIN), else use LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Akina exactly, I need to produce 1 row only. JOIN will give me a row for every = comparison unless I use LEFT JOIN maybe.

Comment: Strawberry HA HA HA VERY FUNNY! I tried to use INNER join but I get a ton or rows.

Comment: Anyway even if 1992 it works! Good old fashion is not obsolete yet.